# Is there ever a correct time to use a public variable?

Tags: java, global-variables, public

Is there a situation were using a public variable would be beneficial?  If not, why do they even exist?

Also I am specifically talking about Java, but if they have use in another language perhaps that would give reason to their existence.

Comment: Sure, for application-wide `static` constants.

Comment: static constants are public all the time!

Comment: `public static final <type> CONSTANT = VALUE` - but in more general terms - you should let us now the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @ns47731 `private static final` is not public

Comment: @SteveKuo miss interpretation, I am not saying all the time literally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I use them for my representation of a vector.

```
public class Vec3f {

    public final float x, y, z;

    // the methods

}
```

Note that because these are **final primitives** it is safe to expose them. This is shorter in code and uses less method calls (none).

In general, they are viable to use in **value-objects** (let's use that name) if made final. 
I define value-objects as possibly immutable, possibly short-lived objects holding just data, yielding new objects on mutation.

You shouldn't use public non-final variables in your public API though...

Comment: I agreed with everything up to *"You shouldn't make non-final variables public though..."*, while certainly good advice, I don't see it as a hard and fast rule, things like Point, Dimension, Insets for example expose non-final fields. I would suggest that where the field is not "managed" or "calculated" or part of a greater whole (other fields are relying on it and need to now when it's changed) it is a possible candidate for been exposed as public, but it would require more context before a decision could be made - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I meant a public API, where I really don't want to see public fields. Sorry for that formulation.

Comment: Point, Dimension, Insets have been around since Java 1.0, back when there was the perceived performance penalty of methods. Now a days getters will most likely be inlined.

Answer (score 0):

public ***static final*** variables are a common and handy way of defining constants

Public member variables are a little harder to justify, but I have seen a massive number of bean type objects with a load of private member variables and a corresponding set of getters and setters that do nothing but return or set the private variables. In those cases, there is an argument to make those variables public as the data is hardly "encapsulated" by the class - the user can set it to whatever they like, and they retrieve whatever the variable is set to without any modification.

I don't do it personally, but I'm not 100% against it either.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables (when the language allows), can cause major problems especially in complex systems, where a piece of code can change its value at any time. Besides creating a coupling between places that should not have.

so avoid

In java I usually use public final constants in a single centralized source.